# Snap Camera on Zoom doesn't work well

Tags: windows-7, zoom-meeting, snap-camera

I have installed Snap Camera on my PC (Windows 7) i can see the Snap Camera in my video setup on Zoom, but when When choose it I just see Snap Camera logo, with some short flicker every 30 sec or so. 
BTW, when I open Snap Camera the video+filter looks great. Tried to restart apps, PC, re-install and install both applications, and play with all video definition under Zoom setup (e.g. HW acceleration, but nothing changes it). Please advise.

After checking some more, same thing when I use Skype, so it is most likely not related to zoom only